# How to Dynamically change the style of a react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been attempting to create a react app similar to monkeytype; where letters are formatted as the user types them. I've created a word functional component that wraps  tags, but I'm running into trouble now as I try and dynamically format a bunch of these word components depending on user input. One idea I have is to store these Word components in an array then use array indexing to call a method on the Word components that needs to be updated, but I've never experienced with react component objects or understand how the object methods work. (From what I observe, you can't call methods on react components?) Here's an example of what it looks like, how can I, say, at run-time allow the user to navigate to the "Current" word and style that word conditionally?

```js
import Word from './word'; 
import './typeTest.css'

export default function TypeTest() {
    const test1 = "the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree"; 
    const test1Arr = test1.split(' '); 
    
    return (
        <div className='outer-word-container'>
            <div className="word-container">    
                {test1Arr.map(monoWord => <Word inputWord = {monoWord}/>)} 
                <Word inputWord="Scoll"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be appreaciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question asked, I tried to have a sample of making dynamic `style` which depends, in my case, on the index of the array. Changing colors of the background made me come up with this solution:
**App.js**

```
import { Word } from "./word";
//import './typeTest.css'

export default function App() {
  const test1 =
    "the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree the quick brown fox jumped over a tree and tripped over that tree";
  const test1Arr = test1.split(" ");

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
        {test1Arr.map((monoWord, index) => (
          <Word
            inputWord={monoWord}
            style={{
              background: `#${(index*2).toString(16)}${index.toString(16)}${((index+1)/2).toString(16)}`
            }}
          />
        ))}
        <Word inputWord="Scoll" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**word.js**

```
export const Word = (props) => {
  return <h1 style={props.style}>{props.inputWord}</h1>;
};
```

As you can see in the `word.js` component we get the props of style, which is applied later to the child component. Passing the background is the most visible change in styles, so I implemented that. The same technique you would use if you implement a `className`, which is conditionally writable as string.   Here is the example in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-shannon-zl7gh?file=/src/App.js).